# Virtual screen size with libgdx and GLES 2

Tags: java, android, libgdx, screen

I've been trying to use a virtual screen size for my libgdx desktop-android game. I'd like to always use a 16:9 aspect ratio but with a virtual screen size so everything would adapt automatically depending on the device size.

[This post](http://blog.acamara.es/2012/02/05/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/) illustrates the process pretty well but my game crashes when camera.apply(Gdx.Gl10) is called. This is because I'm using GLES 2.0 (for not having to use multiple of 2 texture sizes). As stated in the [OrthographicCamera doc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.html), the apply method only works with GLES 1 and GLES 1.1.

Is there another way of applying my GL transformation to the camera so I can use a virtual screen resolution? Having to resize everything manually it's a total pain.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer at here:
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3915

Comment: -1, While this might help the asker, you should at least copy the relevant parts of the link in case that site goes down in the future.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer